# How do I utilize this semi-transparent png so the caption is easier to read in my Jquery slider? (w/ pic)

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have this Jquery slider plugin for Wordpress, and it's just the jquery cycle plugin by Malsup.

Anyway, I added a caption in each slide.  I just can't find a color that shows clearly in each slide.  So I made a semi-transparent (50% opacity) png in Photoshop, 5px x  5 px.  Currently, my CSS looks like this:

```
.homepage-slides p {
background: transparent url('images/title-bg.png') repeat top left;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
color: #000000;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

I also tried using an absolute path to the png, but no go.  Here's the result:

[image: Windmill]

As you can see, the caption in the bottom is almost impossible to read.  It'd be cool if I could find a way to have like ... this semi-transparent, yellow rectangular box and then have the black caption inside that box, so you could read the caption.  Any help with this would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not using images. One reason is that png images with transparent backgrounds don't have transparency in some browsers (I know it maybe only older browsers but still).
Another reason. The image wont be positioned 100% of the background in your script.

I personally like using CSS made backgrounds as they pretty much cover all browsers types. Here's my background example for you :)

```
background:rgba(200,200,200,0.5); //50% silver-ish background.
```

You could use an opacity. But I wouldn't recommend that as it would effect the content in your `p` element as well as. I believe using an alpha filter would do the same but it's been a while since I've used them.

Here's a further example for you :)

```
background:linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(70,70,70,0.5) 30%, rgba(200,200,200,0.5) 100%); 
//from top to bottom 100% transparent black.
//Very dark grey 50% transparent at 30% from the top of the element.
//Silver-ish 100% at the bottom at 50% transparency.
```

using the webkit extensions respectively for the above example :)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The browser that doesn't support alpha transparency on PNGs (IE6) also doesn't support rgba.  In fact, you don't get rgba support in IE until version 9.  Alpha transparency on PNGs, on the other hand, is supported as early as IE7 or IE8 (caniuse lists IE8, but I'm almost positive IE7 has it as well).  Also, you don't get gradients until IE10 unless you're using `filter`!

Comment: @cimmanon Well yea that's why I said use webkits respectively. I meant filters by that too! It's just there are more webkits lol. Plus IE is pretty useless. I was thinking does IE 6 and 7 support `rgba` when I was writing this. Is there a work around you know of that isn't `opacity`?

Comment: Perfect! Do you have an IE fix for that?  Having issues in IE8, but I'm sure I can get it to work.  Anyway, thanks for sharing the knowledge, Beneto; I just tried the first solution, and the effect was exactly what I wanted. Now you can actually see the title clearly and it still has some opacity so it looks professional. Thanks for taking the time to help -- appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your comment Cimmanon ... yes, I'll find a hack for IE8 and below, although if they're still using dinosaur browsers, most websites probably don't show up as the developers want 'em to, so screw 'em ... lmao.

Comment: @JasonWeber No problem :) well you could do a `:before` element for IE 8. Like `#smallDiv:before{background:#FFFFFF;opacity:0.5;position:relative;content:' ';}` but the problem I have with that is trying to make it the same width and height as the element `p`. Also it doesn't work for 5.5-7 :(

Answer (score 2):

Mr.Jason

Try this Html and Css,

```
    <body>
    <div class="stroke-effect">
        This text should have a stroke in some browsers
    </div>
    </body>
```

Css

```
    body{
    background-color:#000;
    }
    .stroke-effect{
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #ffffff,
    1px -1px 0 #ffffff,
    -1px 1px 0 #ffffff,
    1px 1px 0 #ffffff;  
    }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/VqDKp/

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Verikat ... thank you for taking the time to try to help.  Perhaps I'm not doing something properly, but I tried your solution and couldn't get it to function properly in all browsers.  But I'm sure there's something I'm not doing correctly, as your jsfiddle clearly shows how to use this.  I'm going to save your answer and see if I can combine it with Beneto's answer and maybe see if I can come up with something.  Thanks again for your time!